# Could someone explain how those variables change in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

could someone please explain me, what happnes in every step of this code:
    y += (int)(x++ - (float)y-- / ++a)
which results in changing variables. I would like to know what happens in each step of it. 
I'm starting with:
`x = 9`, `y = 4`, `a = 2.5`
and ending with: 
`x = 10`, `y = 11`, `a = 3.5` 
Thank you!

```
 int x = 9;
 int y = 4;

 float a = 2.5f;

 Console.WriteLine("x = " + x);
 Console.WriteLine("y = " + y);
 Console.WriteLine("a = " + a);
 Console.WriteLine();

 Console.WriteLine("y += (int)(x++ - (float)y-- / ++a) = " + (y += (int)(x++ - (float)y-- / ++a)));
 Console.WriteLine();

 Console.WriteLine("x2 = " + x);
 Console.WriteLine("y2 = " + y);
 Console.WriteLine("a2 = " + a);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Take a look at the C# documentation for the [++ operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator) - it's well explained.  -- operator works the same way.

Comment: I did, thank you. Anyway I'm not getting this formula. y += (9 - 4 / 2,5) = 9 - 1,6 = 4+7,4 = 11,4.. I'm totally lost :S

Comment: Best solution is simply not to write code like this. Modifying a variable multiple times in a single expression is hard to understand. Just break it into multiple statements.

Comment: @CoolBots The tricky part is the `+=` operator. But basically, you shouldn't write code like this. Because it creates problems like this question.

Comment: It's part of my homework :) I would not write it like that ever.. I think I figured it partially, but I would still appreciate if someone could explain it to me. It something like: X goes to 10, Y goes to 3, X-Y is 7, Y+= Y(4) + 7 = 11. so X end on 10 Y on 11 and A on 3,5 (as a++ leads to +1). I'm not getting that "/".. Shouldn't this divide something? Thanks

Comment: @34GL3 re: __it's part of my homework__  - that is unfortunate!

Comment: @CoolBots I totally agree;

Comment: Grab a pencil and paper and work it through. Or use the debugger to step through the code. This is simple math.

Comment: This is a bad homework question because (1) the answer is very specific to C#'s order-of-evaluation rules and does not generalize to other languages, and (2) it implicitly encourages writing unreadable code like this.

Comment: Geez, the poor OP is getting killed because of a lack of understanding something clearly designed to be hard to understand. I guess learning comes from being raked over the coals :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the IL that is created by the code `y += (int)(x++ - (float)y-- / ++a);`:

```
IL_0017:  ldloc.1 (y) 4
IL_0018:  ldloc.0 (x) 4|9
IL_0019:  dup         4|9|9
IL_001A:  ldc.i4.1    4|9|9|1
IL_001B:  add         4|9|10
IL_001C:  stloc.0 (x) 4|9                   10 -> x
IL_001D:  conv.r4     4|9f
IL_001E:  ldloc.1 (y) 4|9f|4
IL_001F:  dup         4|9f|4|4
IL_0020:  ldc.i4.1    4|9f|4|4|1
IL_0021:  sub         4|9f|4|3
IL_0022:  stloc.1 (y) 4|9f|4                3 -> y
IL_0023:  conv.r4     4|9f|4f
IL_0024:  ldloc.2 (a) 4|9f|4f|2.5f
IL_0025:  ldc.r4 (1f) 4|9f|4f|2.5f|1f
IL_002A:  add         4|9f|4f|3.5f
IL_002B:  dup         4|9f|4f|3.5f|3.5f
IL_002C:  stloc.2 (a) 4|9f|4f|3.5f          3.5f -> a
IL_002D:  div         4|9f|1.142857f
IL_002E:  sub         4|7.857143f
IL_002F:  conv.i4     4|7
IL_0030:  add         11
IL_0031:  stloc.1 (y)                       11 -> y
```

The left-most column is the memory location, next is the instruction, third (in brackets) is the variable stored locally, and finally the values that are pushed on to the stack with a `|` separating values on the stack. I've shown integers as the plain number and floats with a `f` suffix.

Key to this code is that `y` is pushed on to the stack first - that's when it is `4`. The value for `y` is updated in two places `IL_0022` & `IL_0031` - the first time the value `3` is stored, but that is overridden when `11` is.

The IL was created with optimizations off.

The net result is that this computation has side-effects that sets `x = 10` and `a = 3.5f` after effectively computing `y = 4 + (int)(9f - 4.0f / (2.5f + 1f))`.

Comment: Thank you for this! :) May I ask, how have you triggered this memmory output?

Comment: @34GL3 - I used LINQPad to get the IL and I just built up the stack manually by following the instructions.

Comment: @34GL3 - No worries. It would be awesome if you'd up-vote and accept. The other answer is misleading and just plain wrong on a number of points.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have accepted your answer, but I'm unable to upvote since my reputation is too low. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

your code is casting some numerical values as INT and FLOAT to avoid number errors.

x++  will use the current value of x, and then after it is used in that statement it will increment by 1

++a will increment the value +1, and then it will use the value in the statement

y-- will use the current value of y, and then after it is used in that statement it will decrement by 1

y += ....   will basically do  "  y = y + **_ " where the _** is the calculated value of the statement

For the order in which operators are performed... [link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) ... that page shows operators starting with the highest precedence to the lowest. The operators within each section share the same precedence level.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Except that the compiler will throw away the change of `y` by the `++` because it is used in the `y +=` (which uses the original value of `y` as if it were `y = y + ...`).

Comment: Ok I came to something like this: y += 9 - 4 / 3,5  .. y = 4 + 5 = 11 / 3,5 ..  what happens with ` / ++a` ? shouldn't this number be used to divide?

Comment: So far answer does not cover order of evaluation in the statement and hence not very useful - please update (don't forget to provide references to C# specification)